# React Js Proxy not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, redux

I am totally new to `react`. Here, I am trying to make an `API` request. 
So I set proxy in package.json like

```
  "proxy": {
    "/proxy": {
      "target": "http://localhost:9000",
      "pathRewrite": {
        "^/rez": ""
      },
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  }
```

My react app is on `localhost:8080`. Now, Second way I used

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:9000"
```

and I used it in the action,
 with the hep of the `axios`

```
const request = axios.post('/rez/login', values);
```

But This is not working, It is not making any call to the `9000`, Its using `8080` . What is the way to do this ?. I have gone through all the github and stack questions but not able to get this working. Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me I didn't include the proxy:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
     proxy: {
     "/api": "http://localhost:9000"
     }
 },
```

and when I called the api route it went `/api/getUsers` etc...

Comment: So you added this in the webpack config ?

Comment: Yes I put it in the webpack config.

Comment: Yes, It works in webpack but I want to have it in the package.json

Comment: I see. I'm not sure about the package.json way I must of interpreted your question wrong my apologies.